# I need to create a hundred self-signed certificates with no PEM Pass Phrase

Tags: ssl, certificate, pem, passphrase

I have several hundred testing virtual-hosts on a private server.  I need to *automatically* generate self-signed SSL certificates for each of them, but I'm running into a problem:  "Enter PEM Pass Phrase."

I do not *want* a pass phrase.  I do not want to enter a pass phrase a hundred times.  (And the "-passin pass:blah" option appears to do nothing... I am *still* prompted.)

Furthermore, each key must correspond to the virtual-host name ("/CN=blah") to which it will eventually be placed.

So, I have an immediate need for "somebody's script that does this."  **Help!!**

Comment: What tool are you using to make certificates? As it stands, no one could answer this.

Comment: I'm using the openssl command.  I started with this:  openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout xyz.key -out xyz.crt -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=Tennessee/L=Somewhere/O=myco/OU=Com/CN=www.testserver.local"  ... and I get a pass-phrase prompt.

Comment: I need to put some command or set-of-commands into a **loop** to crank out all the certificates that I need.  Each certificate should require no passphrase to be supplied by Apache, and I need to generate them without entering anything.  There's no "real" security matter here:  the production systems (different URLs) use SSL, so the test virtual-hosts must also.  (And, I know that this is "a thing already done" by some kind soul out there ...)  :-)

Comment: Despite what is said in "http://openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/req.html" and specifically in "https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/openssl.html" (under *Pass Phrase Arguments*), attempts to use **-passin pass:foobar123** did *not* prevent me from getting prompted to enter a phrase!

Comment: What's confusing here is that with the version of OpenSSL installed by macOS 10.15 (Catalina), LibreSSL 2.8.3, the help text produced by `openssl req -x509 -h` shows only the `-passin` argument, the `-passout` argument is *not* listed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, how about that ... I think I just answered my own question!

The command-line parameter I needed was "-pass**out**," not "-pass**in**."

-pass"out" defines the "output password source," and this apparently qualifies as an "output password."

-pass"in" defines the "input password source," but there is no such thing in this case.  The option is ignored.

---

And the next thing you need to do, of course, is to remove the key.

So, the sequence of commands that I believe will do the job is:

(1) Create the key, with a dummy password, e.g.:

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout my.pass.key -out my.crt -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=company/OU=Com/CN=www.testserver.local" -passout pass:ABCDABCD

(2) Now generate a password-free key:

openssl rsa -in my.pass.key -out my.key -passin pass:ABCDABCD

(3) "Kill the spare" ...

rm my.pass.key